# Vue Router 4 layout does not render children

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router4

Using **Vue-Router 4** in a **Vue 3** project, I am encountering a strange issue where `Main.vue` is being rendered correctly, but `Home.vue` is not being rendered inside it.

I have another layout named `FullPage.vue` that opens and renders correctly with either `Login.vue` or any of the other two.

- If I go to */* only `Main.vue` is rendered
- If I go to */login*, `FullPage.vue` with `Login.vue` inside is rendered
- If I go to */non-existent-route*, `FullPage.vue` with `404.vue` inside is rendered

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

**Main.vue**

```
   <template>
        <div>
        main
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="content-area">
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        Home
    </div>
</template>
```

**FullPage.vue** and **Login.vue** have the same structure

```
<template>
    <div class="full-page">
        full page
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<template>
    <div>
        login form
    </div>
</template>
```

**router.js**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { store } from './store/store'

const router = new createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/'),
    routes: [
        {
            // MAIN LAYOUT ROUTES
            path: '',
            component: () => import('@/src/layouts/main/Main.vue'),
            meta: { requiresAuth: true },
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    name: 'home',
                    component: () => import('@/src/views/Home.vue'),
                }
            ],
        },
        // FULL PAGE LAYOUT
        {
            path: '',
            component: () => import('@/src/layouts/full-page/FullPage.vue'),
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'login',
                    name: 'login',
                    component: () => import('@/src/views/pages/Login.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'error-404',
                    name: 'error-404',
                    component: () => import('@/src/views/pages/404.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'error-403',
                    name: 'error-403',
                    component: () => import('@/src/views/pages/403.vue')
                },
            ]
        },
        // if no match found, redirect to /error-404
        {
            path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
            name: 'not-found',
            redirect: '/error-404'
        }
    ],
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
            next()
        }
        else {
            next({ name: 'login' })
        }
    }
    else {
        next()
    }

})

export default router
```

An important clue is that if instead of just a forward slash for path (`'/'`) I put in something like `'/home'` it starts to work as it should.

Comment: is the path correct? `'@/src/views/Home.vue'` doesn't include `/pages` in its path like your other child components.

Comment: @yoduh Yes, the path is correct.